# How to draw text with white spaces in blackberry.?

Tags: blackberry

I am in big trouble,I want to draw text on the image.I insert string from EditField and when i enter string which is wrapped or you can say it contains new line character.but when i get string from editfield using edifield.getText() it convert that string in to single line. But actually i want string like it is in editfield.

For example in edit field i insert string like this:

```
Hi,
How are you?
```

Then editfield.getText() gives me "Hi,How are you?".

So how to get original text for editfield?

Please Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @mdm , I didn't do more stuff.Just get the text from editfield using editfield.getText() and store it in one string variable and draw on image using paint method.I want the original text without removing any white space or newline char for editField.

Comment: Ok, but how the EditField is created and added to the interface is quite important as it is possible to alter fundamental behaviours of the underlying BasicEditField control that the EditField uses. I would like to help you but unless you can provide an example of how the EditField is instantiated, then it will be very hard for me to give you an appropriate answer. Have you created a class that derives from EditField or BasicEditField, or are you just using the regular EditField on it's own?

Comment: @mdm Thanx for giving response.I find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ans ,how to draw multiline text:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Can-drawText-wrap-text-into-multiple-lines/td-p/258808